# Delete amazon s3 object by versionId using rest API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete amazon s3 object using rest API but not getting any success. I have created the URL(signed url) at server side using java and then made XHR request to that URL at client side(i.e. from browser).

Java code that i have used to sign the url:

```
    public static String getSignedURL(String fileName, int fileOwnerId, String versionId){
    Date expiration = new Date();
    long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
    milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 10; // Add 10 minutes.
    long seconds = (milliSeconds)/1000L;
    String URL = null;

    try {
        String encodedFileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
        String canonicalizedResource = "/"+AWS_BUCKET_NAME+"/" + fileOwnerId + "/" + encodedFileName;
        String stringToSign = "DELETE\n\n\n" + seconds + "\n" + canonicalizedResource +"?versionId="+versionId;
        byte[] keyBytes = AWS_SECRET_API_KEY.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(signingKey);

        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes());
        byte[] base64bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(digest);
        String signedString = new String(base64bytes, "UTF-8");

        String signature = URLEncoder.encode(signedString, "UTF-8");

        URL = "https://"+AWS_BUCKET_NAME+".s3.amazonaws.com/" + fileOwnerId +
                "/" + encodedFileName +"?versionId="+versionId +"&Expires=" + seconds+"&AWSAccessKeyId=" +
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY + "&Signature=" + signature;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {

    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {

    }

    System.out.println("URL IS :"+URL);
    return URL;
}
```

And at client side:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("load", deleteComplete, false);

    xhr.open('DELETE', URL_GENERATED_FROM_SERVER, true); 

    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    xhr.send();
```

Using this code for downloading an object from amazon s3 bucket works fine by replacing 'DELETE' request with 'GET'. But delete is not working. I have searched a lot but there is very less help available for rest API.

Comment: why you add fileOwnerId to stringToSign?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @okwap . I have added that because thats the way i have saved files on s3. like bucketname/username/file.txt

Answer (score -1):

Finally, i integrated the aws sdk to delete the object from amazon s3 bucket and it works like lightning. But unable to get help doing it with rest API. So now i have used rest API for uploading and downloading and the sdk for deleting an object.